# Filtration of data sent to the Internet

Tags: android, android-source

I have the following question. Premises for this question are the following. I want to filter data that are sent to the Internet from any application. A user should have possibility to change these filters.

Findings: I have found that I can put filters libcore/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/luni/platform/OSNetworkSystem.java class. But the problem is that the filters are defined on the frameworks level (in my service) and I cannot send the information from this service to this class (I guess because this class is in the core.jar and my service is in the frameworks.jar). Does anybody have ideas how to do this? Is this possible in general or not?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found an answer. There are two possibilities to do that:

1. IP tables
2. To use Java reflection API.